# How can I delete the hidden .svn folder on my local working copy using php on a remote server? Unlink() permission denied

Tags: php, svn

My `SVN` repository contains multiple projects. Each project contains the same structure that looks like `trunk -> doc -> log.txt`. This `log` file contains the changes made between revisions.
 Currently I created a `php` script that executes when a server build is run. This `php script` checks out `log.txt` file on the server's local directory. `C://..../..../doc/log.txt`.

It writes into this file and then commits the changes. The problem occurs when someone runs the server build with another project. It tried to check out the `log.txt` file of that project into the same directory and I get an `svn error`. I no longer need the checked out files in the local directory once the changes have been committed. The only option I could think of is to delete the doc folder (only in my local directory not the repo) before checking out the new one so that the previous `log.txt` is no longer there.

I found a `recursive algorithm`that deletes all files with `unlink()` and directories with `rmdir`. The algorithm works well. Unfortunately, the hidden `.svn` files do not `unlink()` with permission denied errors. Using `fileperms()` on all files and parent directories gives back `16895` which translates to `40777` in `octal`, so I believe they have full permissions. But I believe permissions for users do not have modify/write. Is there a proper way to delete the hidden `.svn folder` on my server's working copy? Alternatively if anyone can think of a better method to do this. So if `AprojA/doc/log.txt` is already in the local directory and I check out `BprojB/doc/log.txt`. Is there a way to checkout and overwrite the existing `log.txt` with the log file from another project? --force parameter doesn't seem to do much for me.

I also had a vague idea of maybe checking out the top level svn repo with -depth=empty. and then svn update just the log txt files of each project. So instead of `checkingout -> committing changes -> deleting`. I can just have all `log.txt` files available. But the problem is they all have the same folder and file name of `(doc/log.txt)`. Still relatively new to all this so I'd appreciate feedback of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

u can use wild cards to delete the log files with the extension. so all files of the same extension will be deleted under the selected folder.